# What's wrong with this (very simple) divisibility proof?

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

In the Book of Proof (Richard Hammack) there's an exercise that asks you to prove this:

> Suppose $a$ is an integer. If $7|4a$ then $7|a$.

My attempted solution was simply this:

If $7|4a$ then there is an integer $b$ such that

$4a=7b$

Then $a=\frac{7b}{4}$

which is obviously divisible by 7. If it's necessary to be extremely explicit I suppose I could add

Let $c=\frac{b}{4}$. Then $a=7c$, and so $7|a$, from the definition of divisibility.

But when I looked at the solution provided in the back of the book, it was way more complicated than this, and involved the definitions of odd and even numbers, and uses a few more dummy variables.

I can follow the solution, but what I don't understand is, what's wrong with my solution?

Comment: The "obviously divisible by $7$" needs more details. In the extra details, you need to explain why $c$ is INTEGER, as you are using this in the next step.

Comment: Consider what goes wrong with the "obvious" claim when you change $7$ to $8,\ $ i.e. $\, 8\mid 4a\ \not\Rightarrow\, 8\mid a.\ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are implicitly assuming that $\frac b4$ is an integer, which is actually what you're trying to prove. If you find yourself writing fractions in these kinds of problems, you're usually doing something wrong.